# Using XmlWriter to create large document from LINQ to SQL / LINQPad throws Out of Memory Exception

Tags: sql-server, out-of-memory, linqpad, xmlwriter

I'm trying to export data in a LINQPad script and keep receiving Out of Memory exception.  I feel like the script is doing all 'streamable' actions so not sure why I'm getting this.

The main loop of the code looks like the following.  A few notes:

1) The first query returns around 60K rows `profileDB.Profiles.Where(p => p.Group.gName == groupName).Select( d => d.pAuthID )`

2) The second query for each `pAuthID` returns rows in a the database where one field is a Xml blob of data stored in a string field.  It is not that big...< 500K for sure.  Each `pAuthID` row could have as many as 50 rows of FolderItems.  The query is `profileDB.FolderItems.Where(f => f.Profile.pAuthID == p && ( folderTypes[0] == "*" || folderTypes.Contains(f.fiEntryType) ) ).OrderBy(f => f.fiEntryDate)`

3) I only write a single line to the result pane when the processing starts.

4) The script runs for a long time, throwing exception when the output file is around 600-700MB.  Huge I know, but it is a requirement that we dump out all the data into Xml.

5) The `WriteFolderItems` function/loop will be pasted below the main loop.

6) I call `XmlWriter.Flush` after each *xDataDef* element.

```
using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = false } ) )
{
    xw.WriteStartElement( "xDataDefs" );

    foreach( var p in profileDB.Profiles.Where(p => p.Group.gName == groupName).Select( d => d.pAuthID ) )
    {
        if ( totalRows == 0 ) // first one...
        {
            string.Format( "Writing results to {0}...", fileName ).Dump( "Progress" );
        }

        totalRows++;

        var folderItems = profileDB.FolderItems.Where(f => f.Profile.pAuthID == p && ( folderTypes[0] == "*" || folderTypes.Contains(f.fiEntryType) ) ).OrderBy(f => f.fiEntryDate);

        if ( folderItems.Any() )
        {
            xw.WriteStartElement("xDataDef");
                xw.WriteAttributeString("id-auth", p);

                xw.WriteStartElement("FolderItems");
                    WriteFolderItems(profileDB, datalockerConnectionString, xw, folderItems, documentsDirectory, calcDocumentFolder, exportFileData);
                xw.WriteEndElement();

                xw.WriteEndElement();

            xw.Flush();
        }
    }

    xw.WriteEndElement();
}
```

*WriteFolderItems* has looping code as well that looks like the following.  A few notes:

1) I'd expect the `foreach( var f in folderItems )` to be streaming

2) For some of the FolderItem rows that are Xml blobs of cached documents, I need to run ~ 1-5 queries against the database to get some additional information to stick into the Xml export: `var docInfo = profileDB.Documents.Where( d => d.docfiKey == f.fiKey && d.docFilename == fileName ).FirstOrDefault();`

3) I call `XmlWriter.Flush` after each FolderItem row.

```
public void WriteFolderItems( BTR.Evolution.Data.DataContexts.Legacy.xDS.DataContext profileDB, string datalockerConnectionString, XmlWriter xw, IEnumerable<BTR.Evolution.Data.DataContexts.Legacy.xDS.FolderItem> folderItems, string documentsOutputDirectory, string calcDocumentFolder, bool exportFileData )
{
    foreach( var f in folderItems )
    {
        // The Xml blob string
        var calculation = XElement.Parse( f.fiItem );

        // If it contains 'cached-document' elements, need to download the actual document from DataLocker database
        foreach( var document in calculation.Elements( "Data" ).Elements( "TabDef" ).Elements( "cache-documents" ).Elements( "cached-document" ) )
        {
            var fileName = (string)document.Attribute( "name" );

            // Get author/token to be used during import
            var docInfo = profileDB.Documents.Where( d => d.docfiKey == f.fiKey && d.docFilename == fileName ).FirstOrDefault();

            if ( docInfo != null )
            {
                document.Add( new XElement( "author", docInfo.docUploadAuthID ) );
                document.Add( new XElement( "token", docInfo.docDataLockerToken ) );
            }

            // Export associated document from DataLocker connection...XmlWriter is not affected, simply saves document to local hard drive
            if ( exportFileData && DataLockerExtensions.ByConnection( datalockerConnectionString ).Exists( calcDocumentFolder, (string)document.Attribute( "name" ), null ) )
            {
                using ( var fs = new FileStream( Path.Combine( documentsOutputDirectory, fileName.Replace( "/", "__" ) ), FileMode.Create ) )
                {
                    string contentType;
                    using ( var ds = DataLockerExtensions.ByConnection( datalockerConnectionString ).Get( calcDocumentFolder, (string)document.Attribute( "name" ), null, out contentType ) )
                    {
                        ds.CopyTo( fs );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Write the calculation to the XwlWriter
        xw.WriteStartElement( "FolderItem" );
            xw.WriteElementString( "Key", f.fiKey.ToString() );
            xw.WriteElementString( "EntryDate", XmlConvert.ToString( f.fiEntryDate.Value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Local ) );
            xw.WriteElementString( "ItemType", f.fiEntryType );
            xw.WriteElementString( "Author", f.fiAuthor );
            xw.WriteElementString( "Comment", f.fiComment );
            xw.WriteStartElement( "Item" );
                calculation.WriteTo( xw );
            xw.WriteEndElement();
        xw.WriteEndElement();
        xw.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is EF make sure you've turned off change tracking, or the DbContext change tracker will retain references to each loaded eneity.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: It is L2S, but has the same concept and I discovered that turning that off solved the issue.  I forgot to come back and answer.  Throw an answer out there and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you disable Change Tracking, or the EF or L2S Change Tracker will retain references to each of the loaded entities.